minio.error.S3Error: S3 operation failed; code: AccessDenied, message: Access Denied., resource: /musor-bucket
Create the bucket
mc mb local/musor-bucket --debug

Create the credentials pair
mc admin user add local musor-user musor-top-secret-key --debug

Create the policy to grant access to the bucket
# cat musor-bucket-policy.json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
   {
    "Sid": "AllowBucketSync",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
     "s3:GetObject",
     "s3:ListBucket",
     "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::musor-bucket",
     "arn:aws:s3:::musor-bucket/*"
    ]
   }
  ]
 }

Add policy to your minio instance
mc admin policy create local musor-bucket-policy ./data/musor-bucket-policy.json --debug

Associate policy with your user
mc admin policy attach local musor-bucket-policy --user=musor-user --debug

You can verify that everything is setup as you’d expect by running this
# mc admin user info local musor-user
AccessKey: musor-user
Status: enabled
PolicyName: musor-bucket-policy
MemberOf: []

Try to connect by python
from minio import Minio
from minio.commonconfig import SnowballObject
from urllib3 import PoolManager


access_key="musor-user"
secret_key="musor-top-secret-key"


pool_manager = PoolManager(
    ca_certs="minio/tls-ca-bundle.pem",
    cert_reqs="CERT_REQUIRED",
)

client = Minio(
    "minio.local:443",
    access_key=access_key,
    secret_key=secret_key,
    secure=True,
    http_client=pool_manager
)

print(client.bucket_exists("musor-bucket"));

return error
minio.error.S3Error: S3 operation failed; code: AccessDenied, message: Access Denied., resource: /musor-bucket, request_id: 180F0EC003737710, host_id: 03f6d7ba09b0531a178059659f12e65ab6a75adddf2f548b1f37624d55d95fba, bucket_name: musor-bucket

How solve this problem?

I assume the bucket_exists() method requires some permission other than the three you have allowed.

You right, change "Action" to "s3:*" solve problem.

The error Access Denied usually means that the MinIO policy is not properly attached, or the user does not have the necessary permissions for the bucket. Let’s troubleshoot and solve the issue step-by-step.
You need to update the bucket policy to include the s3:HeadBucket action. Update your musor-bucket-policy.json as follows:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBucketSync",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:HeadBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::musor-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::musor-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

check : https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/identity-access-management/policy-based-access-control.html

s3:HeadBucket - not enough,
working if use s3:*

https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/identity-access-management/policy-based-access-control.html : depending on this website, you will need also : s3:GetBucketLocation and s3:ListAllMyBuckets. will update the answer, so it may help other people , least permission is always better.

it now ok, working, thanks
